# How do I simply quit a job I never "officially" worked for

Tags: resignation

So my situation seems strange, to me. Last month, almost exactly last month, in fact, I took up a job working for a very, very small bakery quite a ways from where I live. It was never official that I worked there, however, as I only received cash and never a paycheck. Even my boss told me it was a bit "under the table". It was only meant to be a..."permanent" thing; just a trial period to see if it worked.

And it doesn't work for me. I suffer from severe depression, anxiety and more and working here has made it worse. I won't go into detail...but I felt horrible working there.

How should I do this? I never officially worked there, so should I simply give an email stating my resignation? Or should I call and then give a letter of resignation? Again, this is a very small company, barely even three workers, not including myself. No divisions or anything. Everything is handled by the boss. So...I don't know how to go about this professionally.

Comment: For the future, never accept a job that pays under the table It is illegal to pay under the table so those are ALWAYS bad jobs because the owner has poor ethical values.

Answer (score 6):

Arguably, there's no "professional" way to quit a job that you're working illegally off the books.

But as Joe said in his comment, tell your boss face-to-face that you're quitting.

The advice I would add to that is to pick a time which isn't going to leave you with too much work not yet paid for. e.g. if you normally get paid cash at the end of the week, don't quit on Thursday after working Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. There's a risk your boss will just kick you out and never pay you for that work. Quit as soon as possible after receiving your next pay.

Answer (score 4):

E-mail will work. It's be more polite to do it face-to-face.

It's customary in the US to give two weeks' notice, so they have a bit of time to find your replacement before they lose you. But if you really absolutely can't cope, you can quit effective immediately, though that may mean you can't use them as a reference. Then again, it sounds like you haven't been there long enough for a meaningful reference anyway.

Unsolicited advice from another depressive (stabilized): if it is keeping you from doing what you want/need to do, you need to get it treated. You wouldn't ignore a broken arm; this is not very different, really.

Comment: Seconding keshlam's "unsolicited advice".